# How to execute a http request without opening browser in java?

Tags: java

I have executed the requests using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` method. But my tool requires that I have to execute the `request` without opening the browser.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Why you are not trying java HTTP client ? There are lot of example on internet.

Comment: can u explain a bit more.. about what do you mean by executing requests? If you want to perform a httprequest without browser, you may take a look at the apache httpclient api.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at HTTP client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a linux machine, why dont you try executing the curl command.

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm

Comment: I am using a windows machine.

Comment: I think this link will help you then - http://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget